# How can I set 'selected' value for an option which has square brackets in it id name?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

I want to read the value of the select tag which has [] in its id.

```
<select id="jobtype[]" class="dropDown" size="4" multiple="multiple" name="jobtype[]">
<option value="28">Activity staff/ Resort Rep</option>
<option value="1">Admin/ Secretarial/ Clerical</option>
<option value="2">Advertising/ Marketing/ PR</option>
<option value="29">Art/ Design</option>
<option value="30">Au Pair/ Nanny</option>
```

I am using the function below for setting 'selected':

```
$("#jobtype\\[\\] option").each(function()
            {
                //if ($(this).val() == 39)
                { 
                    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                }

            });
}
```

Comment: Id attribute should not have []

Comment: Your code works as-is (if you fix the syntax errors around the brackets), but there are no options with a value of 39. http://jsfiddle.net/w7vRv/

Comment: Take a look at this for why it shouldn't have square brackets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: yes there are no options with value = 39.. i just gave an example dude...

Comment: As of HTML5, the only requirement for ID's is it must contain at least one character, and it can't contain any spaces. It doesn't say thing about not using `[]`

Comment: @ManojKumar In that case your code works as-is, if you fix the mis-matched brackets.

Comment: @adeneo following w3c html specs, but like Kevin said html5 is more permisive. But i'm sure you know that :)

Comment: @roasted - In this day and age, hopefully everyone is using the HTML5 doctype, where it's completely valid with brackets in the ID selector. Should you use it just for fun, probably not, but some frameworks seems to do it all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, escaping the brackets should work just fine :

```
$("#jobtype\\[\\] option[value=39]").prop('selected', true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WgPg9/)

Comment: I am able to get values of all the <option tags> under <select>. I want to set 'selected = selected' fot that tag which has value 39!.. $(this).prop('selected', true); is not working

Comment: In what version of jQuery? And you do of course have an option with that value, see my fiddle ?

Comment: I am using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2

Comment: I have put this code in a function and on change of a drop down menu, i am calling this function.

Comment: Then you're using terribly outdated code, and I refuse to help you until you upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: I will try out with the latest version now.. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2e3tY/1/, so there are other problems:

Try:

1. The `select` tag should be closed
2. The jquery function should be wrapped in $(function() { } ); so it is called on doc ready.

Comment: yes I agree .. select tag is to be closed.. I am just giving an example. It is closed actually.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work just fine, here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/LxKrS/1/

```
$("#jobtype\\[\\] option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 29) { 
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }    
});
```